# Error appear when finished update wordpress

Tags: wordpress, updates

my website today show error relative to update, but i dont know why it appear at the top my website . ".update-nag , .error, .updated{ display:none; } ".
pls help me solve this problem.
[image]

Comment: i think you have placed styles without <style></style> tag

Comment: You have some error in you style sheets. Please search that and  remove that

Comment: I suggest you search your project for `.update-nag`.

Comment: i already search but i still remaning . it have all  pages even show at wp-admin page